# Determine JSON path when a field contain dots (in the format of session.content)

Tags: java, json, rest, maven

Below is a portion of the response I am getting via REST API call. I am trying to use the response, parse using Java but "session.content" is causing a problem. "fields.'[session.content]'" shows up as null. Hence, I cannot get anything after that. It will say cannot get property on null object. I am using eclipse/maven to run REST APIs with jayaway REST Assured resources/dependencies.

How would I determine the JSON path to:

1. display a specific tokens? [ will it be
   "fields.'[session.content]'..tokens[0]"  ?]
2. get all the fish in one array like {"snapper", trouts" } etc.
3. get all term_freq in one array

Response in JSON:

```
{
"type": "fish",
"area": "local",
"fields": {
    "session.content": {
        "snapper": {
            "term_freq": 2,
            "tokens": [{
                "end_at": 80,
                "start_at": 79
            }, {
                "end_at": 210,
                "start_at": 179
            }]
        },
        "trouts": {
            "term_freq": 2,
            "tokens": [{
                "end_at": 180,
                "start_at": 159
            }, {
                "end_at": 225,
                "start_at": 219
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

}

So far, I am able to access other responses in this format:

> String term23 = json_response.then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).
>   extract().path("fields.'[session.content]'");

where `json_response` is the response received in from REST call in JSON format. Any guidance on how to find those 3 JSON paths to use with Java/jayway will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you're using for parsing. JacksonMapping allows you to put an annotation on a field to specify its JSON name separate from its name in a Java object, where a dot is illegal as any part of a variable name. So I suggest you use that.

Comment: I am using jayway jsonpath/rest assured (from Maven Repository) to do the parsing.

Comment: I am not familiar with it. Does it have a way to do what I suggested, which is to specify the JSON name separately from the java name, and have you tried it?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "specify the JSON name separately from the java name". I have tried to name the path in these ways:  "fields.'[session.content]'..tokens[0]" "fields.'session.content'..tokens[0]" etc.

Comment: "tried to name the path" doesn't tell me anything about what you're trying to do, or where, or in what language, or at what time. The "JSON name" for a field is the part in double quotes and before the ":" -- the name that JSON uses to refer to a field. If you are parsing JSON and ending up with a Java object, then there are variable names inside the class for that object. Often the name used by JSON and the name used by Java match, but in your case that cannot be, because the JSON name has a period in it and the Java variable name cannot.

Comment: The REST call response looks like above JSON. I have saved the response in a variable call json_response. Then, I have converted the String to an Object:  `Object search_result = Configuration.defaultConfiguration().jsonProvider().parse(json_response.asString());` Then, I am using either `String Type= JsonPath.read(search_result, "type"); ` or  `String area= json_response.then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().path("local"); ` to read from the response. I am trying to get other fields in the JOSn response. not sure if this helps to clarify the problem/issue